# How can I make sure that that the number displays correctly on each grid that gets added?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC + EF

I have a Feed xml file url that gets updated every 7 minute with items, every time a new item gets added I retrieve all the items to a list variable and then I add these varible to my database table. After that I fill a new list variable which is my ViewModel from the database table. Then I declare the ViewModel inside my view which is a .cshtml file and loop throught all of the objects and display them.

How can I make sure that the newest items get placed on the top and not in the bottom and also the numbers displays in correct order?

This is how I display the items inside my cshtml note that I use a ++number so the newest item needs to be 1 and so on ::

```
@model Project.Viewmodel.ItemViewModel
@{
    int number = 0;
 }
<div id="news-container">
@foreach (var item in Model.NewsList.OrderByDescending(n => n.PubDate))
{
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="number">
            <p class="number-data">@(++number)</p>
        </div>
        <p class="news-title">@(item.Title)</p>
        <div class="item-content">            
            <div class="imgholder">
                <img src="@item.Imageurl" />
                <p class="news-description">
                    @(item.Description) 
                    <br />@(item.PubDate) | 
                    <a href="@item.link">Source</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                  
}
</div>
```

This is how I fill the viewmodel which I use inside the .cshtml file to iterate throught and display the items

```
private void FillProductToModel(ItemViewModel model, News news)
{
    var productViewModel = new NewsViewModel
    {
        Description = news.Description,
        NewsId = news.Id,
        Title = news.Title,
        link = news.Link,
        Imageurl = news.Image,
        PubDate = news.Date,
    };
    model.NewsList.Add(productViewModel);
}
```

If you check this image thats how it gets displayed with the numbers, thats incorrect.

If you see the arrows thats how it should be, how can I accomplish that?

[image]

Any kind of help is appreciated :)

note: When I remove `.OrderByDescending`, the numbers are correctly on each grid. But I need the `.OrderByDescending` beacuse i want  the latest added item in the top.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddel with the rendered html.

Comment: and your `PubDate` also in the wrong order for 6 and 5 ? Maybe you should first check your `Model.NewsList.OrderByDescending(n => n.PubDate)` result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@model Project.Viewmodel.ItemViewModel
@{
    int number = 0;
    var NewsItems=Model.NewsList.OrderByDescending(n => n.PubDate).ToList();
 }
<div id="news-container">
@foreach (var item in NewsItems)
{
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="number">
            <p class="number-data">@(++number)</p>
        </div>
        <p class="news-title">@(item.Title)</p>
        <div class="item-content">            
            <div class="imgholder">
                <img src="@item.Imageurl" />
                <p class="news-description">
                    @(item.Description) 
                    <br />@(item.PubDate) | 
                    <a href="@item.link">Source</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                  
}
</div>
```

Comment: You are welcome...glad it worked. I wasn't quite sure it would.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sketch I assume you have `float: left` or `display: inline-block` for a `grid` class. Adding `float: right` might do the trick.

If that does not help please post CSS you have.

Answer (score 0):

just a quick word..

you are passing NewsViewModel to the view and performing iteration on ItemViewModel ..y?
do u think this may be the cause of the problem..

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could sort your news list using the [CompareTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) method:

```
model.NewsList.Sort((a, b) => b.PubDate.Date.CompareTo(a.PubDate.Date));
```

Once you have the list sorted correctly, you can simply use CSS to display the news list two items per row. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taBec/1/).

The fiddle is a revised one which was provided to me in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15955067/displaying-a-generic-list-two-list-items-per-row-when-using-a-foreach-loop) I asked before.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
private void FillProductToModel(ItemViewModel model, News news)
{
var newList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.News.Date).toList();
var productViewModel = new NewsViewModel
{
    Description = newList .Description,
    NewsId = newList .Id,
    Title = newList .Title,
    link = newList .Link,
    Imageurl = newList .Image,
    PubDate = newList .Date,
};
model.NewsList.Add(productViewModel);
```